# Does Sqlite Like only work on the first letter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have the following code to use the Where and And filter.

```
public void Add(Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, object memberValue)
{

    if (_Query.ToString() != string.Empty)
        _Query.Append(" AND ");

    _Query.Append(string.Format(" [{0}] = {1}", NameOf(memberExpression), memberValue == null ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", memberValue)));
}
```

I took this same method and made some changes to use Like in sqlite but only works with the first letter entered if entering 2 letters no longer brings any value

Code Like:

```
public void Like(Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, object memberValue)
{

    if (_Query.ToString() != string.Empty)
        _Query.Append(" AND ");

    _Query.Append(string.Format("  [{0}]  LIKE '{1}' ", NameOf(memberExpression), memberValue == null ? "NULL" : "%" + memberValue + "%"));
}
```

With a letter
[image]

With more than 1 letter
See that you should bring the record "William"
[image]

For anyone who is talking about sql injection I simply got this Sqlite example and I'm doing a little crud.

[EXAMPLE CRUD](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-sqlite-with-c-sharp/)

Edit:
[image: In debug it looks generated sql]

sql to run on "Db browser for Sqlite"
[image]

**Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLiteWithCSharp.Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Author : Swaraj Ketan Santra
    /// Email : swaraj.ece.jgec@gmail.com
    /// Date : 25/02/2017
    /// Description : Entity/model classes as T 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Class and newable type</typeparam>

    #region Attributes
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this attribute to decorate the properties on your model class.
    /// Only those properties that are having exactly the same column name of a DB table.
    /// </summary>
    public class DbColumnAttribute : Attribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Set true if implicit conversion is required.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Convert { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Set true if the property is primary key in the table
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Denotes if the field is an identity type or not.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsIdentity { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region BaseService
    /// <summary>
    /// Use with Entity/Model class only
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        #region Constructor
        public BaseService()
        {

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Pass the connection string in constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        public BaseService(string connectionString)
        {
            Context.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// To get SQLite connection object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>SQLiteConnection object</returns>
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return new SQLiteConnection(Context.ConnectionString);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts the single record into table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public long Add(T entity)
        {
            long identity = 0;
            bool hasIdentity = false;

            StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

            IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = GetPropertyInfoList(entity);

            foreach (PropertyInfo i in propertyInfos)
            {
                var ca = i.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) as DbColumnAttribute;

                if (ca != null)
                {
                    if (!ca.IsIdentity)
                    {
                        columns.Append(string.Format("[{0}],", i.Name));
                        values.Append(string.Format("{0},",
                               i.GetValue(entity) == null ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", i.GetValue(entity))));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hasIdentity = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (columns.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {

                columns.Remove(columns.Length - 1, 1); // Remove additional comma(',')
                values.Remove(values.Length - 1, 1); // Remove additional comma(',')

                StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
                qry.Append(string.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}] ( {1} ) VALUES ( {2} ); SELECT last_insert_rowid();"
                    , entity.GetType().Name, columns, values));


                identity = hasIdentity ? Execute(qry.ToString(), true) : Execute(qry.ToString());
            }

            return identity;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts multiple records into a table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities"></param>
        public void AddRange(IList<T> entities)
        {
            StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (T entity in entities)
            {
                StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

                IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = GetPropertyInfoList(entity);

                foreach (PropertyInfo i in propertyInfos)
                {
                    var ca = i.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) as DbColumnAttribute;

                    if (ca != null)
                    {
                        if (!ca.IsIdentity)
                        {
                            columns.Append(string.Format("[{0}],", i.Name));

                            values.Append(string.Format("{0},",
                                i.GetValue(entity) == null ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", i.GetValue(entity))));
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (columns.ToString() != string.Empty)
                {

                    columns.Remove(columns.Length - 1, 1); // Remove additional comma(',')
                    values.Remove(values.Length - 1, 1); // Remove additional comma(',')


                    qry.AppendLine(string.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}] ( {1} ) VALUES ( {2} );"
                        , entity.GetType().Name, columns, values));
                }
            }

            try
            {
                Execute(qry.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates single entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();

            IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = GetPropertyInfoList(entity);
            foreach (PropertyInfo i in propertyInfos)
            {
                var ca = i.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) as DbColumnAttribute;

                if (ca != null)
                {
                    if (!ca.IsPrimary)
                    {
                        columns.Append(string.Format("[{0}] = {1},", i.Name,
                            i.GetValue(entity) == null ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", i.GetValue(entity))));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        clause.Append(string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", i.Name, i.GetValue(entity)));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (columns.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                columns.Remove(columns.Length - 1, 1);
                StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
                qry.Append(string.Format("UPDATE [{0}] SET {1} WHERE {2};"
                    , entity.GetType().Name, columns, clause));


                Execute(qry.ToString());
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Updates mutiple entities in single query
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities"></param>
        public void UpdateRange(IList<T> entities)
        {
            StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (T entity in entities)
            {
                StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();


                #region MyRegion
                IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = GetPropertyInfoList(entity);
                foreach (PropertyInfo i in propertyInfos)
                {
                    var ca = i.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) as DbColumnAttribute;

                    if (ca != null)
                    {
                        if (!ca.IsPrimary)
                        {
                            columns.Append(string.Format("[{0}] = {1},", i.Name,
                                i.GetValue(entity) == null ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", i.GetValue(entity))));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            clause.Append(string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", i.Name, i.GetValue(entity)));
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (columns.ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    columns.Remove(columns.Length - 1, 1);

                    qry.AppendLine(string.Format("UPDATE [{0}] SET {1} WHERE {2};"
                        , entity.GetType().Name, columns, clause));
                }
                #endregion
            }

            Execute(qry.ToString());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find single item
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmdText"></param>
        public T GetById(object id)
        {
            T entity = new T();
            StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();

            IList<PropertyInfo> pInfos = GetPropertyInfoList(entity);

            foreach (var pi in pInfos)
            {
                var pk = pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) as DbColumnAttribute;
                if (pk != null && pk.IsPrimary)
                {
                    clause.Append(string.Format("[{0}]='{1}'", pi.Name, id));
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (clause.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
                qry.Append(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE {1}", entity.GetType().Name, clause));
                var _entities = ExecuteGet(qry.ToString());
                if (_entities != null && _entities.Count > 0)
                    entity = _entities[0];
            }


            return entity;
        }
        public IList<T> Find(IEnumerable<object> ids)
        {
            IList<T> entities = new List<T>();
            StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();

            var entity = new T();
            IList<PropertyInfo> pInfos = GetPropertyInfoList(entity);

            foreach (var pi in pInfos)
            {
                var pk = pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) as DbColumnAttribute;
                if (pk != null && pk.IsPrimary)
                {
                    string _ids = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var id in ids)
                    {
                        if (_ids != string.Empty)
                            _ids = _ids + ",";

                        _ids = _ids + id.ToString();
                    }

                    clause.Append(string.Format("[{0}] IN ({1})", pi.Name, _ids));
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (clause.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
                qry.Append(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE {1}", entity.GetType().Name, clause));
                entities = ExecuteGet(qry.ToString());
            }

            return entities;
        }
        public IList<T> Find(IFilter<T> filter)
        {
            T entity = new T();
            return ExecuteGet<T>(filter);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get all records
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmdText"></param>
        public IList<T> GetAll()
        {
            T entity = new T();
            return ExecuteGet(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", entity.GetType().Name));
        }        
        /// <summary>
        /// Pass comman text to get values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="commandText"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IList<T> GetAll(string commandText)
        {
            return ExecuteGet(commandText);
        }
        public IList<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>(string commandText)
            where TEntity : class, new()
        {
            return ExecuteGet<TEntity>(commandText);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Execute Only ; No return
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmdText"></param>
        //private void Execute(string cmdText)
        //{
        //    using (var connection = GetConnection())
        //    {
        //        connection.Open();
        //        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, connection);
        //        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //    }
        //}
        private long Execute(string cmdText, bool returnIdentity = false)
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, connection);

                if (returnIdentity)
                {
                    return (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Execute and get records. of the native type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmdText"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IList<T> ExecuteGet(string cmdText)
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, connection);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return new EntityMapper().Map<T>(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get list of items by specifying the type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmdText"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IList<TEntity> ExecuteGet<TEntity>(string cmdText)
            where TEntity : class, new()
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, connection);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return new EntityMapper().Map<TEntity>(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Pass filter to get records in entity format
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="filter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IList<TEntity> ExecuteGet<TEntity>(IFilter<TEntity> filter)
            where TEntity : class, new()
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(filter.Query, connection);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return new EntityMapper().Map<TEntity>(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Pass SQLite reader to get the specified entity type
        /// when you are reading dataset or multiple records
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IList<TEntity> ExecuteGet<TEntity>(SQLiteDataReader reader)
            where TEntity : class, new()
        {
            return new EntityMapper().Map<TEntity>(reader);
        }
        private IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfoList(T entity)
        {
            return entity.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) != null).ToList();
        }
        private IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfoList<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        {
            return entity.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) != null).ToList();
        }
        #endregion


    }
    #endregion

    #region Cache/Storage
    public static class Context
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Entity Mapper

    public class EntityMapper
    {
        // Complete
        public IList<T> Map<T>(SQLiteDataReader reader)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            IList<T> collection = new List<T>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T obj = new T();
                foreach (PropertyInfo i in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(DbColumnAttribute)) != null).ToList())
                {

                    try
                    {
                        var ca = i.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DbColumnAttribute));

                        if (ca != null)
                        {
                            if (((DbColumnAttribute)ca).Convert == true)
                            {
                                if (reader[i.Name] != DBNull.Value)
                                    i.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(reader[i.Name], i.PropertyType));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (reader[i.Name] != DBNull.Value)
                                    i.SetValue(obj, reader[i.Name]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
#if DEBUG
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Console.ReadLine();
#endif

#if !DEBUG
                        throw ex;
#endif
                    }
                }

                collection.Add(obj);
            }

            return collection;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region Interfaces

    public interface IFilter<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        string EntityName { get; }
        string Query { get; }

        void Add(Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, object memberValue);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Filter
    public class Filter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, new()
    {

        public Filter()
        {
            _Query = new StringBuilder();
            EntityName = typeof(T).Name;
        }

        public void Add(Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, object memberValue)
        {

            if (_Query.ToString() != string.Empty)
                _Query.Append(" AND ");

            _Query.Append(string.Format(" [{0}] = {1}", NameOf(memberExpression), memberValue == null ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", memberValue)));
        }

        public void Like(Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, object memberValue)
        {

            if (_Query.ToString() != string.Empty)
                _Query.Append(" AND ");

            _Query.Append(string.Format("  [{0}]  LIKE '{1}' ", NameOf(memberExpression), memberValue == null ? "NULL" : "%" + memberValue + "%"));
        }

        public string EntityName { get; private set; }

        private readonly StringBuilder _Query;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns SELECT statement with WHERE clause based on the expression passed; This is CommandText
        /// </summary>
        public string Query
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] {1} {2};"
                    , EntityName
                    , _Query.ToString() == string.Empty ? string.Empty : "WHERE"
                    , _Query.ToString());
            }
        }

        private string NameOf(Expression<Func<T, object>> exp)
        {
            MemberExpression body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (body == null)
            {
                UnaryExpression ubody = (UnaryExpression)exp.Body;
                body = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }

            return body.Member.Name;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Class Employee

```
using SQLiteWithCSharp.Utility;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLiteWithCSharp.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [DbColumn(IsIdentity =true, IsPrimary =true)]
        public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Date_Birth { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Home_Address { get; set; }

        [DbColumn]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [DbColumn]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161818/discussion-on-question-by-will-does-sqlite-like-only-work-on-the-first-letter).

Comment: @itsLex looks to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your video on 0:13 and 0:14. The scroll bar disappears partly at the top. The top part of your table is hidden behind the header.

Comment: I discovered that, the panel moved.
Now that I've seen your msg, why did not you show up before rsrs....

Answer (score -1):

Check if your Sqlite has case sensitive LIKE on.

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=OFF;
```

I modified the String.Format as shown below. You cannot enclose NULL in quotes. So I am composing single quotes also as part of replacement. This works fine for me in sqlite.

```
_Query.Append(string.Format("  [{0}]  LIKE {1} "
    , NameOf(memberExpression)
    , memberValue == null ? "NULL" : "'%" + memberValue + "%'"));
```

Comment: How does that explain why `w` worked and `wi` didn't?

Comment: guys, it has nothing to do with case sensitive I ran the same query through "DB Browser for Sqlite" and both with "Wi" and "wi" run there.
It just does not work in my application.